# Using PHP, how can I send data to the server if this data is saved as JavaScript variables in my website?

Tags: javascript, php, server, send

If I have data stored in JavaScript variables on my website and I want to take this data and send it to the server using PHP, how can I do this? A separate client will then get the data from the server to use. Does the server have an IP address that I need to send the data to? What code will be necessary to do this using PHP?

Comment: this is way too broad for SO. as a broad guide, (1) you would need to use ajax to send or build/send a form using javascript, (2) you would need to create the server side code to receive and do something with that data.

Comment: Thank you for your help but for some reason, ajax isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved using the XMLHttpRequest object in Javascript.
However, since you're new this this I would recommend using jQuery.

This is basically an Ajax request and you will find much more documentation on the internet if you search for that.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thank you for your help but for some reason, the Ajax request isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it using PHP, because PHP is executed on the server only.  However, you could use jQuery's `ajax` function if you want to send data from the client side:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/process-data.php",
  data: {
    // your data (stored in JS variables on the client side)
  },
  success: function() {
    // what do to on success: redirect, maybe?
    window.location.href = "/process-data.php";
  }
});
```

Then, on `/process-data.php`, you could use the data:

```
<?php
  $myData = $_POST['myData'];
  // do something with $myData, or display it
?>
<p>You entered: <?php echo $myData; ?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.